# Ellipsis with surrounding spaces

Tags: spacing

I'd like to get dots without extra spaces before and after; the rendering with `babel` for French is the one I'd like. I need to have breaking spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[french]{babel} % TO SEE THE EXPECTED SPACES.

\NewDocumentCommand{\tdocenv}{O{}m}{%
  \texttt{\textbackslash{}begin\{#2\}#1 %
          \!...\! %
          \textbackslash{}end\{#2\}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tdocenv{TEST}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want `\@` in order to avoid end-of-sentence spacing, which doesn't happen with `babel-french` on because it does `\frenchspacing` at the outset.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[french]{babel} % TO SEE THE EXPECTED SPACES.

\NewDocumentCommand{\tdocenv}{O{}m}{%
  \texttt{\string\begin\string{#2\string}#1 %
          \!...\@\! %
          \string\end\string{#2\string}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tdocenv{TEST}

\end{document}
```

I also show how to get real typewriter font backslash and braces.

[image]

It would make sense to add `\frenchspacing` to `\ttfamily`, so the problem will disappear in every case when you use `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[french]{babel} % TO SEE THE EXPECTED SPACES.

\AddToHook{cmd/ttfamily/before}{\frenchspacing}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tdocenv}{O{}m}{%
  \texttt{\string\begin\string{#2\string}#1 %
          \!...\! %
          \string\end\string{#2\string}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tdocenv{TEST}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great and cleaner code...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [package `ellipsis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ellipsis}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tdocenv}{O{}m}{%
  \texttt{\string\begin\string{#2\string}#1%
          \;\textellipsis\;%
          \string\end\string{#2\string}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tdocenv{TEST}

\end{document}
```

[image]